# Pytorch different outputs between with transpose

Tags: python, numpy, view, pytorch, reshape

Let I have a tensor dimension of (B, N^2, C)
and I reshape it into (B, C, N, N).

I think that I have two choices below

```
A = torch.rand(5, 100, 20) # Original Tensor

# First Method
B = torch.transpose(2, 1)
B = B.view(5, 20, 10, 10)

# Second Method
C = A.view(5, 20, 10, 10)
```

Both methods work but the outputs are slightly different and I cannot catch the difference between them.

Thanks

Comment: First it is unclear how torch.transpose doesn't raise an error as you only pass 2 arguments https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.transpose.html .  However if you did actually manage to transpose A with that method, the outputs being different is expected.  A[0].reshape(20,10,10) is differente than A[0].transpose.reshape(20,10,10). Check out what reshaping does in detail, torch or nunmpy docs don't go into much detail but here's a quick guide: https://blog.finxter.com/numpy-reshape/ . A easy way of understanding it is reshaping preserve the order of the data and transposing does not.

Comment: Because you transpose B before reshaping it, the output matrix is indeed different. Let's imagine you have a 2x2 matrix and you transpose it before casting it into a 1D array, it will of course be different than a non-transposed one even though the values in it are the same, just not in the same order

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference between `B` and `C` is that you have used `torch.transpose` which means you have swapped two axes, this means you have changed the layout of the memory. The view at the end is just a nice interface for you to access your data but it has no effect on the underlying data of your tensor. What it comes down to is a contiguous memory data buffer.

If you take a smaller example, something we can grasp more easily:

```
>>> A = torch.rand(1, 4, 3)
tensor([[[0.2656, 0.5920, 0.3774],
         [0.8447, 0.5984, 0.0614],
         [0.5160, 0.8048, 0.6260],
         [0.1644, 0.3144, 0.1040]]])
```

Here swapping `axis=1` and `axis=2` comes down to a batched transpose (in mathematical terms):

```
>>> B = A.transpose(2, 1)
tensor([[[0.4543, 0.7447, 0.7814, 0.3444],
         [0.9766, 0.2732, 0.4766, 0.0387],
         [0.0123, 0.7260, 0.8939, 0.8581]]])
```

In terms of memory layout `A` has the following memory arangement:

```
>>> A.flatten()
tensor([0.4543, 0.9766, 0.0123, 0.7447, 0.2732, 0.7260, 0.7814, 0.4766, 0.8939,
        0.3444, 0.0387, 0.8581])
```

While `B` has a different layout. By *layout* I mean memory arrangement, I am not referring to its *shape* which is irrelevant:

```
>>> B.flatten()
tensor([0.4543, 0.7447, 0.7814, 0.3444, 0.9766, 0.2732, 0.4766, 0.0387, 0.0123,
        0.7260, 0.8939, 0.8581])
```

As I said reshaping *i.e.* building a view on top of a tensor doesn't change its memory layout, it's an abstraction level to better manipulate tensors.

So in the end, yes you end up with two different results: `C` shares the same data as `A`, while `B` is a copy and has a different memory layout.

Answer (score 4):

Transposing/permuting and view/reshape are **NOT** the same!
[`reshape`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.reshape.html#torch.reshape) and [`view`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.view.html#torch.Tensor.view) only affect the `shape` of a tensor, but d not change the underlying order of elements.
In contrast, [`transpose`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.transpose.html#torch.transpose) and [`permute`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.permute.html#torch.Tensor.permute) change the underlying order of elements in the tensor. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53940813/1714410), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67868643/1714410) for more details.

Here's an example, with `B=1`, `N=3` and `C=2`, the first channel has even numbers 0..16, and the second channel has odd numbers 1..17:

```py
A = torch.arange(2*9).view(1,9,2)
tensor([[[ 0,  1],
         [ 2,  3],
         [ 4,  5],
         [ 6,  7],
         [ 8,  9],
         [10, 11],
         [12, 13],
         [14, 15],
         [16, 17]]])
```

If you correctly transpose and then reshape, you get the correct split into even and odd channels:

```py
A.transpose(1,2).view(1,2,3,3)
tensor([[[[ 0,  2,  4],
          [ 6,  8, 10],
          [12, 14, 16]],

         [[ 1,  3,  5],
          [ 7,  9, 11],
          [13, 15, 17]]]])
```

However, if you only change the shape (i.e., using `view` or `reshape`) you incorrectly "mix" the values from the two channels:

```py
A.view(1,2,3,3)
tensor([[[[ 0,  1,  2],
          [ 3,  4,  5],
          [ 6,  7,  8]],

         [[ 9, 10, 11],
          [12, 13, 14],
          [15, 16, 17]]]])
```

---

**Update (Aug 31st, 2022)**
Take a look at this simple example:

```py
# original tensor
x = torch.arange(12).view(3,4)
x.data_ptr()  # -> 94308398597888
x.stride()    # -> (4, 1)

# transpose
x1 = x.transpose(0, 1)
x1.data_ptr()  # -> 94308398597888  (same data)
x1.stride()    # -> (1, 4)  efficient stride representation can handle this

# messing around a bit more:
x1.view(3,4)

# strides cannot cut it anymore - we get an error
RuntimeError: view size is not compatible with input tensor''s size and stride (at least one dimension spans across two contiguous subspaces). Use .reshape(...) instead.

# using reshape:
x2 = x1.reshape(3, 4)
x2.data_ptr()  # -> 94308399099200 (NOT the same data)
x2.stride()    # -> (4, 1)
```

Comment: Hi Shai, old post but I noticed that looking at the `data_ptr` for a given tensor and one of its permuted/transposed versions, it returns the same pointer as the original tensor. It turns out both [`transpose`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.transpose.html) and [`permute`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.permute.html) return a view of the tensor (for strided tensors). The underlying data layout *shouldn't* be changing. Do you why this isn't apparent when flattening the transformed tensors?

Comment: @Ivan I guess there is a difference between the "logical" representation/storage and the physical one: "logically" transposing/permuting changes the underlying order of elements. However, if implemented wisely (which I suspect PyTorch is) in many cases you can change the "logical" order without changing the physical order of elements (using strides etc.). Note that sometimes there's a limit to what "stride tricks" can do and PyTorch will force you to use `reshape` rather than just `view`: this is where elements change their physical order as well.

Comment: @Ivan please see my edit

Comment: Those are two good examples yes. I see now, thank you @Shai.